# Elixir phoenix live reload doesn't work

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

My operating system is the latest macOS high sierra. I installed elixir and all the dependencies via Homebrew. I created a new Phoenix app. It shows some wrong. The live reload doesn't work. Below is the info.

```
[error] Can't find executable `mac_listener`
[warn] Could not start Phoenix live-reload because we cannot listen to the file system.
You don't need to worry! This is an optional feature used during development to
refresh your browser when you save files and it does not affect production.
```

It seems that some file change listener service isn't running. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What happens if you run `./deps/fs/priv/mac_listener` manually?

Comment: @Dogbert No such file or directory. I checked the deps folder. There is no fs  module but a file_system.

Comment: Ah, looks like the dependency's name changed in Phoenix 1.3. What happens if you run `./deps/file_system/priv/mac_listener -h`?

Comment: @Dogbert It show No such file or directory too. I checked the file_system module manually. The priv folder is empty.  There is nothing in it.

Comment: And `mix deps.compile file_system` works?

Comment: @Dogbert I looked the source file of the file_system module on github. There is a exe file in it. I think mac os doesn't need this file.

Comment: @Dogbert It shows miss xcrun. It seems that something wrong with commandlinetools?

Comment: @Dogbert I upgrade my os from sierra to high sierra. I installed command line tools before. Maybe, I need to reinstall it.

Comment: @Dogbert thank you so much. The problem is solved. I reinstalled the command line tools.

Comment: Great! You should post that as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved this problem by reinstalling the command line tools. 
Open the bash, and type in:

```
xcode-select --install
```

And then, run `mix deps.compile file_system` to recompile the file_system module. done.

Comment: This doesn't fix the error in all cases.  Oddly, I have this error popping up in one Phoenix installation but file watching works fine in a separate Phoenix installation on the same machine.  I am baffled.

Comment: Is there another solution regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions above worked for me. In my case what I had to do to get the phoenix live reload working (setup was ok), was to delete the `mix.lock` file and then run `mix deps.get && mix deps.compile file_system`.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer worked for me (running Mojave), but as commented, apparently doesn't work for everyone. Based on this discussion I came across on Elixir Forum it appears to be a persistent issue other users are having issues as well: [Can’t find executable `mac_listener` - [error] exited in: GenServer.call](https://elixirforum.com/t/cant-find-executable-mac-listener-error-exited-in-genserver-call/8886/14)

One user notes they still had issues after trying all of the following:

- uninstall Xcode
- remove Command Line Tools
- mix deps.clean --all && rm -rf _build deps
- reinstall Xcode
- run xcode-select --install, accept the license agreement
- reboot
- run mix deps.get && mix deps.compile file_system
- locate /CoreServices.h
- export CFLAGS="-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include"

The last step that appears to have helped that particular user was to run the following: `open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`

Another Catalina user suggested to set the correct headers path in .bash_profile by running `export SDKROOT="$(xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)"`and then recompiling the deps.

Hope this additional information helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the solution doing this since I already have the xcode-select installed:

```
 sudo xcode-select --reset
```

and then:

```
mix deps.compile file_system
```

You can check if are installed with: `xcode-select -v`
fot the path:  `xcode-select -p`